# Hangman program in Python with a run-time error

Tags: python, runtime-error

## Text based Hangman program

My program runs at first, and is fine until a user enters a letter then has an error where the letter is not defined.  Any ideas? Thanks

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ["""
  
 +---+
 |   |
     |
     |
     |
     |
=========""", """

 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
     |
     |
     |
=========""", """

 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
 |   |
     |
     |
=========""", """

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
 =========""", """

   +---+
   |   |
   O   |
  /|\  |
       |
       |
 =========""", """

   +---+
   |   |
   O   |
  /|\  |
  /    |
       |
 =========""", """

   +---+
   |   |
   O   |
  /|\  |
  / \  |
       |
 ========="""]
words = "ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra".split()

#missedLetters = ""
#correctLetters = ""
#secretWord = ""
def getRandomWord(wordList):
     # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
     wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
     return wordList[wordIndex]

#secretWord = getRandomWord(words)

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print

    print "Missed Letters:",
    for letter in missedLetters:
         print(letter, )
    print

    blanks = "_" * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks: # show the secret word with spaces in between each letter
         print letter,
    print
```

Right here's where i'm getting my main error, when a user inputs a letter, a guess, and it comes as not defined

```
def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
     # Returns the letter the player entered. This function makes sure the player entered a single letter, and not something else.
    while True:
        print("Guess a lowercase letter")
        g = input("-->")
        if len(g) != 1:
            print "Please enter a single letter."
        elif g in alreadyGuessed:
            print "You have already guessed that letter. Choose again."
        elif g not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print "Please enter a LETTER."
        else:
            return g

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
    print "Do you want to play again? (yes or no)"
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

print("H A N G M A N")
missedLetters = ""
correctLetters = ""
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False
guess = ""


while gameIsDone == False:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
    aGuessed = missedLetters + correctLetters
    # Let the player type in a letter.
    guess = getGuess(aGuessed)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        # Check if the player has won
        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllLetters = False
                break
        if foundAllLetters:
            print("Yes! The secret word is " + secretWord + "! You have won!")
            gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedLetters = missedLetters + guess

        # Check if player has guessed too many times and lost
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print "You have run out of guesses!\nAfter " + str(len(missedLetters)) + " missed guesses and " + str(len(correctLetters)) + " correct guesses, the word was " + secretWord + ""
            gameIsDone = True

    # Ask the player if they want to play again (but only if the game is done).
    if gameIsDone:
      if playAgain():
          missedLetters = ""
          correctLetters = ""
          gameIsDone = False
          secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
      else:
          break
```

Comment: Maybe because `while true` is commented out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` in python 2 evals the passed string, you want to use `raw_input()` instead